# rollupjs dist doesn't contain images

Tags: typescript, rollupjs

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

With the following `rollupjs` configuration:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import pkg from './package.json';
import {terser} from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import url from '@rollup/plugin-url';
// delete old typings to avoid issues
require('fs').unlink('dist/index.d.ts', (err) => {});

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs'
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es'
    },
    {
      file: pkg.browser,
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'TextSelect'
    }
  ],
  external: [
    ...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})
  ],
  plugins: [
    typescript({
      typescript: require('typescript'),
    }),
    url({
      destDir: 'dist/assets/',
      // Path to put infront of files (in code)
      publicPath: "./assets/icons/",
      // File name once copied
      fileName: '[name][extname]',
      // Kinds of files to process
      include: [
        '**/*.svg',
        '**/*.png',
        '**/*.gif',
        '**/*.jpg',
        '**/*.jpeg',
      ]

    }),
    terser()
  ]
};
```

This creates the following dist folder:

[image]

As you can see the images are not being placed in the dist folder? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Files under ~14KB are inlined by default. What size are those icons?

Comment: @AluanHaddad okay yeah they are 1kb

Comment: You can configure max size if you don't want them inlined.